# Magento mobile theme - How to create "full website link"

Tags: magento, mobile, hyperlink, web, themes

I use mobile theme for magento
And now I want to create a link to view FULL SITE (if user selects they are taken to the desktop version of the site)
Link to view full site, which enables the user to view the desktop site on mobile.  Once the user has chosen this option they will be unable to return to the mobile site.
The link like in http://m.asos.com
And when I click on View Full Site: asos.com/?stop_mobi=yes&r=2
Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below .htaccess settings for switch between magento full site view and mobile site view for mobile users (Using same base url).

Please note that these settings are not working in your local WAMP server. (In WAMP we can’t assign values for environment variable base on conditions)

Tested Version = Enterprise 1.12.0.2

Mobile store code = mobile

Main site store code = default

All the mobile users will direct to the mobile site when type the www.mysite.com.

To redirect the users to full site you have to use www.mysite.com?___store=default

Likewise to switch back to mobile site again you have to provided with the www.mysite.com?___store=mobile

Note that we can't rely on “___store” parameter since it will be lost with some urls.

Also note that we can't use cookie name store because magento will delete the cookie named “store” when you come back to the default view.

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !___store=default  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !track=default [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:mobile]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store=default  [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:default,CO=track:default:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !___store=mobile  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} track=default [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:default]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store=mobile  [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:mobile,CO=track:mobile:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```